# Обучалка пользователей интерфейсу на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Наверняка каждый натыкался на сайт при посещении в первый раз которого, темнел экран и загорался только какой то конкретный элемент на сайте с выводом сообщения о том что это за элемент и для чего он, как им пользоваться. Этакое обучение сложному интерфейсу сайтов. Помогите пожалуйста найти примеры таких сайтов. Возможно кто то знает как такое называется, есть ли какие то наработки для создания такого обучения на сайте или это всё исключительно с нуля на js+css писать?

Comment: А чего сложного? Для того, что бы выделить определенный элемент, создаем слой, который будет иметь прозрачность и залит черным (блур), даем ему z-index больший, чем максимальный z-index на странице. Элементу, который нужно выделить даем z-index еще больше. Добавляем к выделенному элементу какой-то хелпер, возможно popup. Получится легкая конструкция. Если оформить как функцию js, на входе можно давать только id элемента и текст подсказки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это называется экскурсия по сайту или тур по сайту и другими похожими названиями )

Например тут:

1. http://www.coolwebmasters.com/reviews/3969-11-awesome-jquery-site-tour-plugins-for-guiding-users-with-style.html
2. http://dicim.net/delam-ekskursiyu-po-sajte.html
3. http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=820 (вроде похожий тур как во 2 пункте)
4. https://myrusakov.ru/jquery-tour.html

Comment: Большущее спасибо! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Я рекомендую этот плагин:

https://github.com/easelinc/tourist

пример можно посмотреть здесь:

http://easelinc.github.io/tourist/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Мы использовали [introJS](http://introjs.com/), рекомендую: просто, бесплатно, надёжно.